# Calculate a vector that is perpendicular to Oy axis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a vector perpendicular to $Oy$ axis. Knowing that $v\cdot v_1=8$ and $v\cdot v_2=-3$, where $v_1=(3,1,-2)$ and $v_2=(-1,1,1)$

Comment: Are you aware of the practice of accepting answers to your question? (See [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399).)

Comment: Yes, but I don´t understand your commentaire. Was I rude with someone here. If I was, I´m sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

ley $v=(x,y,z)$ perpendicular to $OY$ axis means that
   $v*(0,1,0)=0$
$v*v_1=3*x+1*y-2*z=8$

$v*v_2=-1*x+1*y+1*z=-3$

$v*(0,1,0)=0 -->y=0$

so $3*x-2*z=8$

$-x+z=-3$   from second   $z=-3+x$ put into first one
$3*x-2*(-3+x)=8$
 $x=2$  and $z=-1$ so we have
$v=(2,0,-1)$

Comment: my friend i am happy that  could help you,just please consider advices from other people and accept their answers,it is rule of this website  ok?it is friendly advice

Comment: Thanks dato. I will consider this in the future.